# Setting a cursor [with CSS] on an image map area

Tags: css

Is there any way to set a `cursor` on an `area` element with CSS? It seems not. This code appears to do nothing at all.

**CSS**

```
area {cursor: help;}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="blah.png" width="800" height="550" alt="Blah" usemap="#blah-map">
<map name="blah-map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="104,86,210,113" href="okgo.htm" alt="OK Go">
</map>
```

The best hack I have been able to come up with is to absolutely position a link on top of that area, and give it the cursor style.

Comment: looks like the only way is to force it by java script...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently had an issue with a css cursor displaying in firefox correctly, but not in chrome or safari.

Long story short, I ended up needed to set display:block; on the area tag. Either my base css, or the browser defaults the tag to display:none;

This was the quick test case I created (check it out [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/toazron1/K3jXj/))

```
<img usemap="#map" src="http://i.imgur.com/9EcEvkn.jpg" height="120" width="100" />
<map name="map" id="map">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,120,100" href="#" />
</map>

area {
    cursor: crosshair;
    display:block;
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: You, sir, are a bad-ass - and that jsfiddle is greatly appreciated.  Nice Floyd image, btw.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct solution, very simple and easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioning a link on top of the image would be my solution/hack as well.

If it's not a vitally important image, you could do this fairly semantically by creating a container with the image as a background, absolutely position the links, and have the link text be the `alt` text you're currently using. Then, use a negative `text-indent` on the links to hide the text from view. It'll work as you intend, but when CSS is disabled, should show plain text links in place of the faux image map.

Comment: I had hoped there was something I was missing, but it seems not. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer as there is a direct solution to question provided. toazron1 has posted the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
#blah-map area{
    cursor:default;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="blah.png" width="800" height="550" alt="Blah" usemap="#blah-map">

<map id="blah-map" name="blah-map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="104,86,210,113" href="okgo.htm" alt="OK Go">
</map>
```

Simply give the map an id then set the cursor type for the area of that id.

Comment: Did you test in chrome and safari?
It seems that it doesn't work in all chrome and safari.

Comment: @SrdjanDejanovic, try setting the _usemap_ attribute of the image to the _name_ of the map.

Comment: 9 years later, no votes - but it works in FF and Chrome.  The selector area alone works too, of course, fine if the same cursor on every map is ok.

Answer (score 1):

With Webkit navigator, CSS :

```
area {cursor: help;} /* or other type */
```

doesn't work, so i use "href", and you can disabled like this

```
<area ... href="javascript:void(0);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by toazron1 works perfectly in WebKit/Safari and doesn't have any bad issue:

**CSS**

```
area {
    cursor: help;
    display: block;
}
```

The idea is to [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) any `area` correctly, so `display: inline` and surprisingly `display: initial` would also work, even if the `href` attribute is not set.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

although this challenge has been answered, i wanted to share a useful IE  workaround i discovered by experimenting.

the issue: i was working with an image map where i did not want the cursor to change to the hand/pointer state on hover. this was for a tool tip (qTip) implementation that required no actual anchor links. i wanted the cursor to remain as an arrow (default state) or have it change to another state on hover.

i could not get IE to acknowledge the styles--the cursor still changed on hover :(

the solution? as a last attempt, i added styles:

```
cursor: default;
display: block;
```

but i associated them also to the image used for the map itself:

```
area, img {cursor: default; display: block;}
```

hope this is helpful to some.