# Change cursor on click for a image map link with css

Tags: html, css, onclick, hover, cursor

I am trying trying to change the cursor when clicking on a link in an image map. I would like to just use css to do this if at all possible. I have seen many things on how to use JavaScript, but I try to use as little script as possible. I made it work so that the cursor changes when you hover the map area, but cannot get it to change again for when the link is clicked. I have tried .class: active, and it works on word links but not on image map areas. Does anyone know a css solution to this issue?

Here is the HTML:

```
    <p>
        Test this <a href="#" class="changeCursor">link</a>
    </p>
    <!--Image -->
    <img src="http://cdn.morguefile.com/imageData/public/files/j/jmiltenburg/10/l/1382316372iut0z.jpg" alt="" usemap="#apple" />

    <!-- ImageMap with a class applied to the area -->
    <map name="apple" id='appleID'>
        <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="circle" coords="225,182,80" style="outline:none;" class="changeCursor" />
    </map>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.changeCursor {
    cursor: crosshair;
}
.changeCursor:active {
    cursor: progress;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/awkkahcc/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a cursor \[with CSS\] on an image map area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502309/setting-a-cursor-with-css-on-an-image-map-area)

Comment: I am looking for a onclick action. For the a element I would use a:active, but I can't get it to work for a map area.

Comment: Yes but the problem you're having is the same as in the linked question - as lin stated below, you can't change the cursor in an image map with CSS. The reason the cursor changed on the image map is because it's now a link (due to the href attribute) and the browser itself styled the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to question, but, as in linked Q/A, a crude sample demo on concept of using anchors instead of map etc.

One can set cursor by using the trick of [@user3920458](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635366/3278057) – but cursor will only change in Chrome and not in Firefox (and probably other browsers) when clicked.

Tested a JavaScript solution, on image map, but that also became very hackish – as Firefox seem to want cursor movement before changing the cursor back, sometimes it does not change at all etc. Guess one could make it work with some more tweaking and hacking, but not sure. Same for Opera.

As an alternative there is the use of anchors and absolute positioning. As a crude demo, here with some border tricks, but would likely be a “squares” solution – depending on how wide browser support is required.

Only tested in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Opera does *not* change cursor on `:active` for anchors. That is: it has some of the same problems as Firefox during the click/mouse down hack for maps – one have to drag the mouse (whilst holding button down) for cursor to change – and is quite buggy.

The only final solution, AFAIK, would be to do it all in JavaScript and targeting MouseDown/Up events etc. on a image or div etc.

[image]

---

### [Example Fiddle using JavaScript solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/Lm9oksf2/)

*OK. In at least Chrome, Firefox and Opera.*

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left    : 0;
    top     : 0;
    width   : 620px;
    height  : 414px;
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
    cursor  : crosshair;    
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntEJ4.jpg);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Check if px/py is inside polygon vx/vy.
function inpoly(vx, vy, px, py) {
    var i, j, c = 0, n = vx.length;
    for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++) {
        if ( ((vy[i] > py) != (vy[j] > py)) &&
             (px < (vx[j] - vx[i]) * (py - vy[i]) / 
                   (vy[j] - vy[i]) + vx[i]) ) {
                c = !c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

// The box.
var box = document.getElementById('wrap');

// X and Y Vectors for polygon around apple.
var vx = [169, 196, 226, 260, 280, 288, 277, 266, 247, 225, 208, 183, 170, 165];
var vy = [142, 122, 118, 122, 136, 173, 209, 229, 238, 242, 241, 223, 195, 169];

box.addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) {
    if (inpoly(vx, vy, ev.clientX, ev.clientY))
        box.style.cursor = 'progress';
});

box.addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) {
    box.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
});
```

---

### [Example Fiddle using CSS with absolute positioned anchor.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/7qnr9sb6/)

*OK. In at least Chrome and Firefox; **not** in Opera.*

#### HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntEJ4.jpg" />
<a href="#" id="target01">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#wrap {
    position: absolute;
}
img {
    position : relative;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
}
#target01 {
    position        : absolute;
    top             : 118px;
    left            : 164px;
    width           : 125px;
    height          : 127px;
   /*-webkit-border-radius: .... */
    border-radius   : 50% 40% 70% 68% / 50% 48% 85% 95%;

    text-decoration : none;
    outline         : none;    
    cursor          : crosshair;

    /* Only for demo purpose to show area. */
    background      : rgba(122,50,222,.5);
}

#target01:hover {
    background: none;
}
#target01:active {
    cursor: progress;
}
```

Comment: I like these options but can any of these options be responsive?

Comment: What do you mean by “responsive”?

Comment: I also use fluid and responsive together, but most of the sites I build are adaptive to the screen size. If you were to adjust the width of your browser, the page adapts to it. So is there a way to create it so that if the image size changes, then this solution would still be possible.

Comment: @kingcobra1986: Ah, hmm. Yes, no. The approach is rather hackish from the get go. It depends a lot on what your end goal is. It looks/sound like you might have to adapt a rather strong JS dependency and do some math. The more complex the shapes, the bigger the code base. Simple squares should be somewhat trivial. One approach could be to look into canvas and more game-style. Again depends a lot on what the goal is. Target mediums would also be a big Q (PC/Tablet/Phone/Watch/Mac/Firefox/Opera/Chrome/IE/Safari ... all / some ...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible without javascript. You can do just as you're doing on the link. Just set display block to the area element, as default browser sets it to none.

```
area {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/brunomuller/awkkahcc/5/

Comment: This works well in chrome, but not firefox. But it is a step closer, thank you.

Comment: Doesnt work ---1, its not possible without JavaScript