# HTML map area tags are not showing pointer cursor when hovered

Tags: html, css, dictionary, area

I'd need to make my area elements appear as pointer cursor to indicate that they are clickable. The flags on the map at the right, 'http://www.metlifecare.co.nz/bay-of-plenty-villages' should appear like they are links.

I'm pretty sure the method I've been using right now to show the `<areas>` as pointer cursors is working before. Somehow, now its not working anymore.

CSS I've been using:

```
area:hover, .hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

Based on the example, `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap` , the area elements are working as a link. However, the flags on the site I'm currently working are not. They should appear the same also.

Am I missing something or any suggestion for alternative to make it work correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a cursor \[with CSS\] on an image map area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502309/setting-a-cursor-with-css-on-an-image-map-area)

Comment: Nope its not working on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved after spending couple of hours looking on the web for a fix.

All what I did was remove the `cursor:default;` applied to the ''. Voila! The `cursor:pointer` applied to map elements are now working.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips and tricks here. Seems you're not alone, at least! :)

[Setting a cursor [with CSS] on an image map area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502309/setting-a-cursor-with-css-on-an-image-map-area)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just changed my post and I've gone through the link you've suggested. Already tried the suggestion but they're not working.

Comment: I can't help really, but wanted to throw that other link your way at least :) Good luck anyway!